# Is There A HTTP Client Class For Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, http

I am currently writing a Android application. I need to connect to a internet web server, send username/password credentials and accept cookies from the server for use for subsequent requests to the same server.

Do you know of a HTTP client class or anything I can use in the SDK that currently supports this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DefaultHttpclient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) and [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) class are already there. You can use either one of this.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) and its [various](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) [implementors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html)?

Answer (score 2):

There is [Resty](http://beders.github.com/Resty) and an Android version available on https://github.com/mravenel/Resty 
(DISCLAIMER: I'm the author)